# After updating Nvidia drivers, receiving the message "Input not Supported"

Tags: drivers, nvidia

In Ubuntu 16.04, after I had installed new drivers for my Nvidia Gtx 1070, and had restarted the computer, now after cycling through several screens of text, it boots to simply the text "Input Not Supported" bouncing around my screen. I am assuming this is a problem with my monitor (Acer R240HY), though lacking any significant experience with either Ubuntu or Linux in general, I have no clue either what causes or how to fix this problem. I have been searching through for threads and people with similar issues, though I have not yet been able to figure out what would the correct process be to resolve this. Outside of just changing things at random, I really do not know how to continue.

Comment: You could try uninstalling the new driver and installing the older one again.

Comment: When I boot my computer, all there is is the message saying "Input Not Supported". Nothing else is displayed on my monitor. I do not know how to access anything else beyond this, which could just be me not knowing how to open any other terminal or menu. I definitely can't find the standard interface.

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: I tried this, but it just sent me back to the same message.

Comment: Does adding "nomodeset" to the boot parameters of the recovery kernel help?

Comment: Adding this to the end of the parameters did not change anything. It is still just saying the same message after booting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem: probably a bad cable or the GPU died.  Does the computer show a BIOS screen?  Can you still get into the BIOS?